# How to get a img file in LocalFolder and display the image

Tags: winrt-xaml

I used this code to get the image file in the localFolder and I encountered the below problem.
The problem is at

BitmapImage src is null even there is data in randomstream

any idea how to overcome this problem? Why BitmapImage is null??

```
string strFilenm = "SDraw-" + prodId.ToString() + ".png";

var folder_path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Img");

StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(folder_path);

StorageFile storagefile = await folder.GetFileAsync(strFilenm);

StorageFile jpgFile = await folder.GetFileAsync(strFilenm);                


IRandomAccessStream randomStream = await jpgFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);    

randomStream.Seek(0);  

BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();

await src.SetSourceAsync(randomStream);   

Image1.Source = src;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert but i think to access file from App LocalFolder you should use something like this:

"ms-appx://LocalFolderName/ImageName.extension"

Answer (score 0):

try writing the instance " BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage(); " at class level.

One reason can be that the code might be trying to access a file that does'nt exist.